# how to show aspx page in contentplaceholder of masterpage

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page in my website.

I have two  contentplaceholder on that master page.
In one contentplaceholder i have some links on which click I want to  redirect 
to the corresponding page in the second contetplaceholder on the same master page.

how can i do this....?

pls help  ..?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have missed something here.  When you use master pages you have content pages instead.  The content page defines the area defined by the content place holder in your master page.  When you create a content page you use the contentplaceholder tags to show your page content within the master page.  It might be worth reading up the [master pages tutorials](http://www.asp.net/learn/master-pages/) on the ASP.NET website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem here. Just make the `.aspx` pages use the same master page and set the link locations to `.aspx` pages.

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like, you'll want to use a sitemap instead of the first contentplaceholder. Here is a description of them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx